# Jquery Ajax call in loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax call in loop for different section and may be some time ajax success function took little more time for processing so for second time when again ajax call happens then error msg comes. can any body tell me how can i handle this ajax call in loop

Below is Example

```
for(var i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
      $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/javascript; charset=utf-8;",
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonpCallback: 'callbackfunction',
                    url: valid URL,
                    data: { 'Parameter List' },
                    success: function (data) {
                        // Some Code
                     },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert('Problem Data.');
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: What error message? Please include that in your question by clicking [edit].

Comment: And what is `// Some Code` doing?